# Rails 3 - logging in a user automatically after creating the account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, authentication

In my `users_controller` I have two methods `signup_process` and `login`. I would like to call `login` automatically for a user after a successful `signup_process` call.

Is this possible? In other language frameworks I would usually just call the `login` controller action direct from the `signup_process` action passing the username and password - but I think that is frowned upon in Rails.

Is there some way instead to *post* the user data to the `users.login` action from my controller?

This must be a common pattern - what am I missing? :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is `login` a pure method or is it linked to a view?

Comment: The login method will redirect to the private part of the site if successful. But it needs posted params, i.e. The login form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by frowned upon, but here's one way

```
class UsersController < ...
   def signup
      // Do some stuff
      do_login(username, password)
      // render or redirect as you wish
   end

   def login
     do_login(username,password)
     // render or redirect as you wish
   end

   private
   def do_login(username,password)
     // do the actual login processing 
     // can even render or redirect here if it's common to both setup and login
   end

end
```

Would that do what you want?

Comment: I agree, abstract away your pure "login" functionality into a private method. Let your action methods be "pure" Request end-points. Actions (public methods in Controllers) should ideally just read parameters, invoke methods on models and render result or redirect. Real business logic ideally belongs in Models. Yes, it's not cool to invoke one action from another.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what does the login action do?

Most likely, it sets something in the session indicating the user is logged in. You could do just that, after creating the user.

It does not make sense to call a controller action, since it's most likely hooked up with a view/form.

Please provide more information on what the login action does, if you still feel like you need to go through it.