# Rails 4: NoMethodError in <Model>Controller#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, nomethoderror

In our Rails 4 app, there are four models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
end
```

Here is our `AdministrationsController`:

```
class AdministrationsController < ApplicationController

  def to_s
    role
  end

  def index
    @user = current_user
    @administrations = @user.administrations
    @calendar = Calendar.new
  end

  def show
    @administration = Administration.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    Administration.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "You successfully quit this calendar"
    redirect_to dashboard_path
  end

end
```

When a new `user` signs up, ie: a new @user is created, he is redirected to his `dashboard`, which corresponds to the `Administration` `index.html.erb` view:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Dashboard') %>

<h1>Dashboard</h1>

<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <% if @user.administrations.any? %>
                <h2>My Calendars</h2>
                <table>
                    <%= render @administrations %>
                </table>
            <% end %>

            <section class="calendar_form">
                <%= render 'shared/calendar_form' %>
            </section>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

At this moment, a user has no calendar and no administration.

So, logically, after we sign up a new user, we get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in AdministrationsController#index

undefined method `administrations' for nil:NilClass

def index
  @user = current_user
  @administrations = @user.administrations
  @calendar = Calendar.new
end
```

We tried to do something like:

```
def index
  @user = current_user
  @administrations = @user.administrations if @user.administrations.exists?
  @calendar = Calendar.new
end
```

but it did not work, and returned a similar error.

How can we fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that `current_user` is returning `nil`, not a user object. Maybe you have created a user but not logged in.

Comment: You are correct: because, we have an authentication system including an email verification system, and we required users to actually activate their accounts before they can log in to their dashboard, then, when we sign up a new user and redirect him to his dashboard, we get the error. Should we redirect to the home page instead, to prevent this problem from happening?

Comment: sure - you could create a `login_required` method in application helper which redirects to a hope page if current_user is nil, and put `before_filter :login_required` at the top of any controller that requires a logged in user

Comment: Will do. Thank you very much. Actually, we have already implemented something similar, with a `def log_in(user) session[:user_id] = user.id end` in our `sessions helper`. However, I read this was not a Rails best practice. Would your solution be a better, safer option?

Comment: it looks like you're trying to log the user in automatically after sign-up - here's a post that describes that process: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916818/rails-3-logging-in-a-user-automatically-after-creating-the-account - in this post `do_login` is the equivalent of your `log_in` function.

Comment: I agree that you probably shouldn't write session variables directly, but rather rely on utility methods built for user authentication; for example, if you're using the Devise gem, it provides methods like `authenticate_user!` and `sign_in(@user)`. Here's a nice article about using Devise: http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/how-to-use-devise-in-rails-for-authentication

Comment: Thank you very much for both links.

Answer (score 0):

you can utilize the [`#respond_to?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F) method

`@administrations = @user.administrations if @user.respond_to? :admininstrations`

Comment: We tried both this solution and the previous one you suggested (with `#try`) and it seems to fix the problem while causing a new error: `NoMethodError in AdministrationsController#index undefined method 'administrations' for nil:NilClass`. The line that may be the root cause of this error is `<% if @user.administrations.any? %>` in the `Administration` `index.html.erb` view file, that I am adding to the question now.

Comment: you should be able to use try there. looking at your models, @user always responds to administrations doesnt it?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The problem seems to come from the fact that we create a user but do not log him in, as pointed out by @FredWillmore. Thanks a lot for your help.